# Pngs being purge when app goes in background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, nscache

I am using AFNetworking to save image from a Url, it uses NSCache to cache the images from the requested urls. When app goes in background and phone is locked, png's are being purged but jpegs are not.I read there is some auto expiration policy in NSCache.

Please help me solve this weird issue.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Basically, few of my images are not loading when app comes back in foreground.

Comment: So basically you want to know how to configure your cache properly?

Comment: Yes, as it it being managed by AFNetworking framework, it must be configured appropriately, my question is why few images are being purged by NSCache, if i can modify the configurations, what they would be?